# Unexpected output when citing in afparticle class (apacite/natbib)

Tags: cross-referencing, natbib, apa-style

I compiled the source below and got the output following:

```
\documentclass[preprint]{afparticle}

\begin{document}

\volumenumber{1}
\issuenumber{1}
\publicationyear{2015}
\publicationmonth{July}
\papernumber{1}
\startpage{1}
\endpage{}

\title{Title}

\author*{First One}
\address{School\par
\path{name@uni.eu}}
\author{Second One}
\address{Institute}

\begin{abstract}
Hi there.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Section}

See \citep{sina,sinb}, and also \citep{za,zb}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[Singh(2013a)]{sina} Singh, A. S. (2013a). Title One
\bibitem[Singh(2013b)]{sinb} Singh, A. S. (2013b). Title Two, etc.
\bibitem[Zingh(2012)]{za} Zingh, B. S. (2012). Title Three
\bibitem[Zingh(2013)]{zb} Zingh, B. S. (2013). Title Four, etc.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image: picture]

I'm trying to understand why I get

> (Singh, 2013a,1) ... (Zingh, 2012,1)

insted of the right one:

> (Singh, 2013a,b) ... (Zingh, 2012,2013)

I suspected some misplaced labelling but I can't see any.

The [`afparticle`](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/afparticle/afparticle.pdf) class uses `apacite` package for bibliography with `natbibapa` option.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style `apacite` uses a different format of `\bibitem` than `natbib`, even if `natbibapa` option is in effect.  It is more verbose.

Here is the right `bibliography` environment for you.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem [\protect \citeauthoryear {%
Singh%
}{%
Singh%
}{%
{\protect \APACyear {2013}}%
{\protect \APACexlab {{\protect \BCnt {1}}}}}]{%
sina}
\APACinsertmetastar {%
sina}%
\begin{APACrefauthors}%
Singh, A\BPBI S.%
\end{APACrefauthors}%
\unskip\
\newblock
\APACrefYearMonthDay{2013{\protect \BCnt {1}}}{}{}.
\newblock
{\BBOQ}\APACrefatitle {Title One} {Title one}.{\BBCQ}
\newblock
\APACjournalVolNumPages{Journal}{}{}{}.
\PrintBackRefs{\CurrentBib}

\bibitem [\protect \citeauthoryear {%
Singh%
}{%
Singh%
}{%
{\protect \APACyear {2013}}%
{\protect \APACexlab {{\protect \BCnt {2}}}}}]{%
sinb}
\APACinsertmetastar {%
sinb}%
\begin{APACrefauthors}%
Singh, A\BPBI S.%
\end{APACrefauthors}%
\unskip\
\newblock
\APACrefYearMonthDay{2013{\protect \BCnt {2}}}{}{}.
\newblock
{\BBOQ}\APACrefatitle {Title Two} {Title two}.{\BBCQ}
\newblock
\APACjournalVolNumPages{Journal}{}{}{}.
\PrintBackRefs{\CurrentBib}

\bibitem [\protect \citeauthoryear {%
Zingh%
}{%
Zingh%
}{%
{\protect \APACyear {2012}}%
}]{%
za}
\APACinsertmetastar {%
za}%
\begin{APACrefauthors}%
Zingh, A\BPBI S.%
\end{APACrefauthors}%
\unskip\
\newblock
\APACrefYearMonthDay{2012}{}{}.
\newblock
{\BBOQ}\APACrefatitle {Title Three} {Title three}.{\BBCQ}
\newblock
\APACjournalVolNumPages{Journal}{}{}{}.
\PrintBackRefs{\CurrentBib}

\bibitem [\protect \citeauthoryear {%
Zingh%
}{%
Zingh%
}{%
{\protect \APACyear {2013}}%
}]{%
zb}
\APACinsertmetastar {%
zb}%
\begin{APACrefauthors}%
Zingh, A\BPBI S.%
\end{APACrefauthors}%
\unskip\
\newblock
\APACrefYearMonthDay{2013}{}{}.
\newblock
{\BBOQ}\APACrefatitle {Title Four} {Title four}.{\BBCQ}
\newblock
\APACjournalVolNumPages{Journal}{}{}{}.
\PrintBackRefs{\CurrentBib}

\end{thebibliography}
```

Of course it is easier to produce this with BibTeX than  manually.

Comment: Oh my God...this compiles indeed sweetly...but the code is pretty tough, isn't it? Should this be my B-plan _only_ in case of those couple of bibitems in (Author, yeara,yearb)? You make me consider to switch to BibTeX immediately instead...

Comment: To tell the truth, I did not write this code manually, but created a `bib` file first.  Apacite is definitely a bibtex-oriented package.  On the other hand, I do not think one can easily make citations 100% compliant with ACA rules manually anyway,

Comment: Yes, I see. I got misleaded by the fact that `natbib` guide starts describing how to set `thebibliography` env, which is my habit, (sadly and) honestly. I think I'll switch to BibTeX in this case. Very useful answer of you, anyway, thank you.